# ASP.Net: Invisible Click Counter which executes multiple Ajax Requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, request

I have a problem. I have a dataTable coming from my database with following structure (I left out Information which is not needed like the `<th>` tag and so on - dataTable is dynamical between 50 and 300 entries):

```
<table>
<tr data-id="34XJ-4">
    <td data-toggle="modal" class="modal-dialog modal-lg sorting_1" data-target="#infoModal" onclick="GetModalDetails()" style="color:darkblue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;">34XJ-4</td>
    <td>Text34</td>
    <td>11568</td>
    <td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr data-id="34TR-8">
    <td data-toggle="modal" class="modal-dialog modal-lg sorting_1" data-target="#infoModal" onclick="GetModalDetails()" style="color:darkblue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;">34TR-8</td>
    <td>Text 234234</td>
    <td>11568</td>
    <td>true</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My GetModalDetails JavaScript function looks like:

```
function GetModalDetails() {
        $('tbody tr').click(
            function () {
                var id = $(this).data('id');
                var JSONData = '{\'id\':' + JSON.stringify(id) + '}';
                makeAjaxCall(JSONData, id);
            });

        function makeAjaxCall(JSONData, id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Test.aspx/getDetails",
                data: JSONData,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    var result = msg;
                    document.getElementById("ModalBody").innerHTML = result.d;
                    document.getElementById("ModalHead").innerHTML = "Orderdetails " + JSON.stringify(id);
                }
            })
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and finally I have an Modal, in which pops up when the click to the first column with detailed Views.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="infoModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="ModalHead"></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h5 class="text-center" id="ModalBody"></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Now this codeis working very well, until I close the modal for the 5th time and  click to the first column of another row without an page refresh.

When I look into my Network Debugging Tools of Chrome I have noticed, that on my first click my ajax request gets the correct ID and passes it to the WebMethod in the CodeBehind. Working well.
But when I close the modal and click to another first column in an other row in the table, ajax request will be executed twice with the correct ID (but the problem is parallel). On the third click, 3 ajax requests are going to be executed, on the 4th click 4 requests and so on. (see screenshot)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE2hK.png)

So the ID is correct given to the WebMethod in the Code Behind, but it is given to often. So I am making for example on the 8th click, 8 similar requests. And then it comes to difficulties in my modal view.

Why is this happening and how can I "disable this invisible" counter? 
Until I click Modal Button "Close", I can not start another Ajax Request.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to make the bind of clicking the TR, simply call your AJAX service when you click on the TD with your function, something like:

HTML:

```
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td data-id="34XJ-4" data-toggle="modal" class="modal-dialog modal-lg sorting_1" data-target="#infoModal" onclick="GetModalDetails()" style="color:darkblue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;">34XJ-4</td>
      <td>Text34</td>
      <td>11568</td>
      <td>true</td>
    </tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    function GetModalDetails() 
    {
     var id = $(this).data('id');
     var JSONData = '{\'id\':' + JSON.stringify(id) + '}';
     makeAjaxCall(JSONData, id);
    }
    function makeAjaxCall(JSONData, id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Test.aspx/getDetails",
            data: JSONData,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                var result = msg;
                document.getElementById("ModalBody").innerHTML = result.d;
                document.getElementById("ModalHead").innerHTML = "Orderdetails " + JSON.stringify(id);
            }
        })
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it's the same problem again. Nothing changed.